# Why is node.js v4.4.5 recommended over v6.2.0 "for most users"?

Tags: node.js, version

I used node.js for a development project a few years ago, and this app is somewhat "mothballed" for the time being — it needs to stay online, it needs to stay secure, but it shouldn't need much attention. It is currently running on node.js v0.10.32, but I would now like invest in a "final" migration to a Long Term Support (LTS) release so it will be easier to maintain for the foreseeable future.

At first glance, the node.js homepage makes it look like v4.4.5 is obviously the only available LTS release:

[image]

However if I click that [LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts_schedule) link, it tells a different story. As far as I can tell, version 6 of node.js is also slated to be an LTS release, with that support ending a full year later than version 4 will be.

Given that:

- v6.2.0 is a versioned release
- v6 is purported to receive LTS maintenance until 2019-04-01
- [theoretically](https://medium.com/@nodesource/node-js-is-semver-8b3938ae8d24) no changes in v6.x should break backwards compatibility

Why would I bother upgrading to v4 instead of v6? Seems like v4 buys me one less year of security patches, but no additional compatibility guarantees?

Comment: Looks like this might be at least somewhat related to a bug the project is tracking regarding LTS messaging: https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/issues/63

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With gratitude to [jasnell](https://github.com/jasnell) and [TheAlphaNerd](https://github.com/TheAlphaNerd) who patiently answered my acerbic questions over on GitHub, here's my understanding of how node.js "long term support" releases are handled:

- All releases based on an even-numbered major branch *are* what other projects might call a "long term support" version. They are promised at least 30 months of support from the first "cut" made available (e.g. a packaged v6.0.0 releases).
- However, the node.js maintainers see "LTS" as more of a release *phase* than a version *type*. While they intend for minor/patch releases made when a major branch is in its active improvement (see "CURRENT" below) phase to be stable and backwards compatible, in the real world they might make mistakes.

So they divide development into [three distinct phases](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule):

1. CURRENT: new features (and bug fixes and security patches)
2. ACTIVE LTS: bug fixes (and security patches)
3. MAINTENANCE: only security patches

**Odd-numbered** major versions get **only the first phase** before being left behind. **Even-numbered** major versions — the ones we're mostly concerned about here — go through **all three phases**.

The CURRENT phase starts with the first public release, and starts the clock ticking on the 30-month support window. They may add significant new features, which should in theory be backwards-compatible but in practice may turn up some issues (new bug gets added, change made to poorly-defined behavior, they fix an old bug you had worked around poorly, etc.)

Then at some point the team decides to move the main development effort to a short-lived odd-numbered major branch (presumably when they need to intentionally break backwards compatibility). At that point the even-numbered branch moves to ACTIVE LTS and they get much more careful with the changes they make: primarily just bug fixes. So if you really want stability, this is the time to get "on board" with a particular release.

Eventually it moves even further to the MAINTENANCE phase, where the code is touched only in response to the most critical bugs (think: security patches). But by then there's probably a new release in LTS "phase" already.

---

So the choice on the homepage right now is between two even-numbered branches, "v4.4.5 LTS" and "v6.2.0 current". If the newer branch were odd-numbered then it would *not* be a good candidate for a production deploy where long-term support is desired.

My actual options are a bit more complex even:

[image: Current node.js version status chart]

I could simply stay on v0.10 which will get critical fixes until October. Or bump up to v0.12 to get those until the end of the year. But neither one of those gains me much, and so I'll rule them out.

I can deploy v4.4.5 which will is still getting general bug fixes right now, and will get security fixes for quite a while yet. This should give me the most stable install. The support cycle is getting to be halfway over already, though — and when it runs out I'll have missed this opportunity now to catch up with some of the major changes that have already happened in v5 and v6.

I am leaning towards deploying v6.2.0, assuming all my dependencies support it right now. This not only buys me a year longer term of "lifecyle remaining", but also gets me fully caught up with any breaking changes that were introduced between v0.10 and now. (It also gets me access to any useful new features — but in this case I don't have a chance to take advantage of it.) The risk I take is that when I update to any hypothetical v6.2.1 or v6.3.0 or beyond that comes along, it might accidentally yield some bad surprises.

In my case I'd rather deal now with the major intentional changes that v5 and v6 have already introduced, and then hopefully be all set (or at least only minor pain) from now all the way until April 2019.

Comment: So, if you want high stability and low risk from future change and can live with 4.x features, you pick 4.4.5.  If you want good stability, latest features, longer maintenance life, but some risk from continued added features you pick 6.x.  6.x is not as baked as 4.x and is more likely to accidentally introduce a bug from a new feature being added, but it has more features and has a longer supported life.

Comment: @jfriend00 yup, afaict that's a great summary!

Comment: Practically speaking, if you're a serious Javascript developer, you're really going to want the ES6 language features in 6.x (perhaps unless you're using a transpiler).  So, for me it would more be about "what are the reasons I shouldn't pick 6.x?".  Since there's no buzz I'm aware of that 6.x is a "buggy" release overall, the only reasons I can find to pick 4.x are if 6.x or a module you need has a bug that affects you or a module you need has not yet supported 6.x.

Comment: @jfriend00 hmm... I'd say the opposite. If you're a "serious javascript developer" I'd prefer a stable platform above all else. Instead of asking "why shouldn't I choose 6.x?" you should ask "why would I accept risk into my project?" If you have a tolerance for risk and believe the benefits of 6.x outweigh that risk, then go for 6.x. Otherwise stick with 4.x, which has been "vetted" by many more real-world projects and developers (at this time.)

Comment: @tyriker - 6.x has been out since April and has a very good stability record.  If you want to a year older version, you're welcome to, but I don't see a reason not to use 6.x.  If you can actually offer any real evidence why one should avoid 6.x, that would be useful information, but just because there hasn't been over a year of passage of time is not a valid reason in my book, especially given how useful the 6.x features are and how good a reputation it has.

Comment: The jump from npm 2 to npm 3 with Node 6.x (with its change in how peerDependencies are handled) has been enough to keep all of our existing projects on Node 4.x. The problems from upgrading all stem from 3rd party modules we've depended on (so problems we're not willing to waste time with, at this time.) This is not a stability issue with Node 6.x per se, but instead a compatibility issue with existing 3rd party modules running on Node 6.x.